# Interior point method with non-negativity constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with the Interior Point Method. 4 variables, 8 constraints, of which 2 enforce non-positivity on variables 1 & 2. How would the entirior point method take this non-positivity into account?

For both I assume to need a Barrier function, which affects the Lagrangian (and therefore the KKT conditions).  Does anybody know how I can successfully incorporate this in the KKT (Newton-Raphson) matrix form?

Thank you for your time.

$
\begin{bmatrix}
... & ... & ... \\ 
... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ...
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x\\ 
\Delta w\\ 
\Delta y
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
...\\ 
...\\ 
...
\end{bmatrix}$

So far I tried the following solution. Given the dummy problem:

---

min $f(x1,x2)$

s.t. 
$h(x) \geq 0$,
$x1 \leq 0$

---

Which for interior point (barrier method) can be rewritten as,

---

min $f(x1,x2) -\mu*log(-x1) - \mu*log(w)$

s.t. 
$h(x)-w=0$

$w, -x_1 \geq 0$

---

Equating the derivative of Lagrangian w.r.t. $x_i$ to 0 yields,

$\nabla f(x) -\nabla h(x)^Ty-\mu*X_n^{-1}e = 0$

where, $X_n = \begin{bmatrix}
-x_1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $e =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Rewriting this results in, 
$X_n \nabla f(x) -X_n \nabla h(x)^Ty-\mu*e = 0$

To define the Newton step it is required to perturb the system (and neglect higher order terms):

($X_n+\Delta X_n) ( \nabla f(x+\Delta x) $+....

$X_n\nabla f(x) + X_n \nabla^2 f(x)\Delta x +\Delta X_n \nabla f(x) +....$ (Equation I)

Finally, to put this in Matrix form (see the beginning of my post) I have to relate $\Delta X_n$ to $\Delta x$. Noting that,

$\Delta X_n = \begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x_1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \Delta x = \begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x_1 \\ 
\Delta x_2
\end{bmatrix} -->  \Delta X_n \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \Delta x $

Though this is not a direct relation. As shown in the last equation, I can only find a relation for the transformed column vector of the diagonal matrix.  only. Not sure if this is the way to go, or if there is an algebraic trick that I miss.

---

Comment: You might find it easier to simply rewrite your problem in terms of nonnegative variables.  If you do stay with non-positive variables, keep in mind that the sign restriction on the Lagrange multipliers will be different from what you're used to with non-negative variables.

Comment: Thank you for your time. In the problem I mentioned I did rewrite the system to non-negative values ($-x1 \geq 0$), I will edit my post to make this more clear. Though in the end I am not sure how to implement this for the interior point algorithm (my suggestion seems not to work, though it can be a bug as well).